# Refreshing a CTreeCtrl when a CDockablePane is resized (double-click on title)

Tags: c++, mfc, refresh

I have a CDockablePane which contain a custom control based on CTreeCtrl.

When I move the CDockablePane, everything is refreshed properly. When I resize the CDockablePane, everyting is refreshed properly. When I double-click on the "title" of the CDockablePane (which snap the CDockablePane to it's original position), the CDockablePane show white as snow, without the CTreeCtrl. I must hover with the mouse and things start to show one treeitem at the time.

I can't believe that this is not "built-in", I must be missing something.
Here is my OnSize and OnPaint function from my CDockablePane.

```
void CLegendeTreePane::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CDockablePane::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if(m_pWndTree)
    {
        m_pWndTree->SetWindowPos(NULL, -1, -1, cx, cy, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOZORDER);
    }
}

void CLegendeTreePane::OnPaint() 
{
    if(m_pWndTree)
        m_pWndTree->AfficheItems();

    CDockablePane::OnPaint(); 
}
```

So, what do I need to add/modify so the CDockablePane refresh everything when resized using the double-click on the title?

Thanks!

Comment: Check OnAfterDockFromMiniFrame method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb983531.aspx

Comment: Nice catch but sadly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and found the workaround.  Firs of all, it seems to happen on MDI Document application and not on SDI Document application.  After comparing with a new project from VS2010 having dockable pane with no problem, I tryed to find why.

In my app, I was registering a new WNDCLASS and using it in the creation of my mainframe to be able to make sure only one app was running using the fonction FindWindow in my app.  When I made this change, everything was now displaying correctly.

## (Before)

```
BOOL CMDIAppApp::InitInstance()
{
    //just before creating doc template

    // Register our unique class name that we wish to use
    WNDCLASSEX wndcls;
    memset(&wndcls, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));   // start with NULL defaults

    wndcls.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wndcls.lpfnWndProc = ::DefWindowProc;
    wndcls.hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

    wndcls.hIcon = LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME); // or load a different icon
    wndcls.hCursor = LoadCursor( IDC_ARROW );
    wndcls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndcls.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    // Specify our own class name for using FindWindow later
    CString csClassName = _T("MyApp");
    wndcls.lpszClassName = csClassName;

    // Register new class and exit if it fails
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wndcls))
    {
        TRACE("Class Registration Failed\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Register the application's document templates.  Document templates
    //  serve as the connection between documents, frame windows and views
    CMultiDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
    pDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_MDIAppTYPE,
           RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIAppDoc),
           RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
           RUNTIME_CLASS(CMDIAppView));

    if (!pDocTemplate)
        return FALSE;

    AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);
}
```

and the in my CMainFrame using it

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{ 
    cs.lpszClass = _T("MyApp");

    if( !CMDIFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
```

## (After)

Remove everything concerning the class registration in your App, it is not there we need to put it, all we have to do is modifying the PreCreateWindow fonction of CMainFrame, making sure the CMainFrame keep all its default windows settings and just changing the ClassName of CMainFrame once created

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
    if( !CMDIFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
        return FALSE;

    // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
    //  the CREATESTRUCT cs

    // Check if our class is already defined
    LPCTSTR pszClassName = _T("MyApp");
    WNDCLASS wndcls;
    if (!::GetClassInfo(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), pszClassName, &wndcls))
    {
        // Get the current requested window class
        VERIFY(GetClassInfo(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), cs.lpszClass, &wndcls));

        // We want to register this info with our name
        wndcls.lpszClassName = pszClassName;

        // Need to preset the icon otherwise the function GetIconWndClass
        // calling us will overwrite our class.
        LPCTSTR pszIcon = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MAINFRAME);
        HINSTANCE hInst = AfxFindResourceHandle(pszIcon, ATL_RT_GROUP_ICON);
        _ASSERTE(hInst!=NULL);
        wndcls.hIcon =     ::LoadIcon(hInst, pszIcon);

        // Register our class now and check the outcome
        if (!::RegisterClass(&wndcls))
        {
            _ASSERTE(!__FUNCTION__ "RegisterClass failed");
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    // Now use our class 
    cs.lpszClass = pszClassName;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Make sure to Unregister your class once your application exit, usually in

```
CMyApp::ExiInstance() 
{
    ::UnregisterClass(_T("MyApp"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar problems when I use the BCG.

When you create this pane use WS_CLIPCHILDREN. This will avid any redrawing problems that the parent tries to overwrite the childs client area...

Comment: Didn't work since I already use this flag. Here is the complete list of flag we use in the creation of the pane: WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_RIGHT | CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN